# Rewriting the item in a list based on input index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

Let's say I have a list:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
```

and i prompt the user to input an index and an item. The program will then look up the index placement in the list and replace the element in the list with the user input item. For example:

```
enter index: 2
enter item to replace: 5
```

the output will be:

```
[1,2,5,4]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

index = int(input("Enter index: "))
item = int(input("Enter item to replace: "))

i = 0
n = len(lst)
while i<n:
    if i == index:
        lst[i] = item
    else:
        i+=1
print(lst)
```

I'm not sure why it isn't printing out anything and I'm pretty sure the logic is as written but I'm guessing my issue is within the while loop?

Comment: Why use a loop at all? When you can do `lst[index] = item`

Comment: Your while loop gets trapped because you never increment i when the i == index.. so once it reaches and replaces the index, it gets trapped in the while loop

Comment: If you just want to replace values the solution of @Moses is correct. But remember if you want to add a new value at index 4 (insert 5th item at end of list) this fails. Then you need the append method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop never terminates because there's never any increment done for the value of `i` when `i == index` - therefore your while loop gets trapped in an infinite loop and it never reaches the end of the program to print out the list

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

index = int(input("Enter index: "))
item = int(input("Enter item to replace: "))

i = 0
n = len(lst)
while i<n:
    if i == index:
        lst[i] = item
    i+=1
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @MosesKoledoye you can just use simple [indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

index = int(input("Enter index: "))
item = int(input("Enter item to replace: "))

lst[index] = item

Enter index: 2

Enter item to replace: 5

print(lst)
[1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Remember that lists are 0-indexed.  If you want to use a 1-indexed list, just use `lst[index + 1] = item`.

Comment: `lst[index] = 3` for `index` a number is not a slice, it's a simple assignment. Slicing implies the indexing of more elements at the same time

Comment: @GPhilo thank you, corrected.  Although technically, isn't [`slice(stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) a valid slice?  That point has always confused me a bit.